# Separar rows por grupo e sua porcentagem do total

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso obter os 10 resultados que mais aparecem em minha tabela e suas respectivas porcentagens, separando por grupos. Por exemplo a tabela:

```
+-----+-----+
|id   |fruit|
+-----+-----+
|  1  | or  |
|  2  | ban |
|  3  | or  |
|  4  | or  |
+-----+-----+
```

ele teria que me retornar algo como:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|COUNT|fruit|PERCE|
+-----+-----+-----+
|  3  | or  | 90% |
|  1  | ban | 10% |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

90% por que ele representa 90% do total de rows e assim vai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa contar tudo, agrupar pelo `fruit` e ordenar pela contagem de cada grupo, limitando em 10. Assim:

```
select count(id) as contagem, fruit, 
    concat(format((count(fruit) * 100 / (select count(*) from tabela)), 0), '%') as percentagem
from tabela
group by fruit desc
limit 10
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/GroupByLimit.sql).

Comment: Ele teria que retornar tambem o nome da fruta

Comment: Claro, esqueci, mas esta é a parte fácil, você já está pegando o jeito para adaptar essas coisas. De qualquer forma editei.

Comment: Seria errado te pedir mais uma ajuda?

Comment: Depende se está diretamente relacionando ou não. Tenta a sorte. Se for algo bom e como não teve outras respostas, aí você poderia editar para deixar a pergunta completa. Mas sempre é importante fazer edições que não invalidem respostas já postadas. Por isto é importante pensar bem antes de perguntar para incluir tudo o que é necessário.

Comment: Fiz a mudança...

Comment: @user3163662 Eu percebo que você não costuma aceitar muito as respostas. É porque elas não respondem a sua pergunta ou porque você esquece? Se esquece, seria legal dar uma revisada nas perguntas que já fez e ver se deve aceitar alguma resposta. Isto é importante para a comunidade.

Comment: Perdao, eu funciono de forma diferente, quando estou a trabalhar num projeto eu penso nas minhas futuras possiveis duvidas e ja as posto para quando eu chegar na duvida ja pode-la resolve-la facilmente e com isso eu tenho varias respostas que me ajudam, mas perdao. irei marcar assim que possivel, Obrigado